# How to Select comboBox values in Selection Changed event

Tags: c#, wpf

```
I have 3 ComboBoxes in WPF form...
```

When i am selecting 1st combox Box values its fill 2nd ComboBox...

but while selecting 1st time comboxBox values its SelectionChanged Event is not working...
After selecting 2nd time its working....

```
 private void cmbBoard_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { cmbClass.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                    cmbClass.DisplayMemberPath = "Class";
                    cmbClass.SelectedValuePath = "ClassID";
                    cmbClass.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing cmbClass.SelectedIndex = 0;, won't that lead to a stackoverflowexception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a more detailed example:

I wrote an example with students and classes.
You have a class which has a name and a collection of students.
And each student has a name.
My classes:

```
public class Class
{
  public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public Collection<Student> Students
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public Class( string name, Collection<Student> students )
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Students = students;
  }
}

public class Student
{
  public string Name
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string FirstName
  {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public string Fullname
  {
    get
    {
      return string.Format( "{0}, {1}", this.Name, this.FirstName );
    }
  }

  public Student(string name, string firstname)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.FirstName = firstname;
  }
}
```

My from contains tow comboboxes and i want that the first one contains all classes and the second one should contains all students which are in the selected class.
I solved this (quick and dirty) in the code behind. I wrote a property for all my classes and mock some data. Here are the important parts:

```
public Collection<Class> Classes
{
  get;
  set;
}

public MainWindow()
{
  this.InitializeComponent( );
  this.Classes = new Collection<Class>( )
  {
    new Class("Class 1",
      new Collection<Student>()
      {new Student("Caba", "Milagros"),
        new Student("Wiltse","Julio"),
        new Student("Clinard","Saundra")}),

    new Class("Class 2",
      new Collection<Student>()
      {new Student("Cossette", "Liza"),
        new Student("Linebaugh","Althea"),
        new Student("Bickle","Kurt")}),

    new Class("Class 3",
      new Collection<Student>()
      {new Student("Selden", "Allan"),
        new Student("Kuo","Ericka"),
        new Student("Cobbley","Tia")}),
  };
  this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Now I create my first combobox with the name cmbClass.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbClass"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Classes}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              Margin="10"
              Grid.Row="0"/>
```

After that I create my second combobox. But to get the itemsSource, i need the value from the first box. So i use an element binding to get the value from the first box.

```
Binding ElementName=cmbClass
```

And i am interested at the SelectedItem of the first box because this item contains a collection of all needed students(see the class above). So i use the path property to solve this.
My second combobox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cmbClass, Path=SelectedItem.Students}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Fullname"
          Margin="10"
          Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Finish!!!

Hope this more detailed solution helps you to understand my way.