# How to bind a textbox.Text property in WPF MMVM design

Tags: wpf, mvvm

So I'm trying to learn the MVVM design patter in WPF, I want to do the following:

In external class I've got a ObservableCollection _students that is bound to a listview on the WPF window using MVVM design pattern. The listview shows only the Student's name and Age.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
}


public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get
        {
            return _students;
        }
        set
        {
            _students = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
        }
    }
```

All good, but I want to put a TextBox and set it to show the listview's selected item's course property. This means I must

1. get the listview's selected index (ok)
2. bind the textbox.Text property to Students[that index].Course

I'm stuck at 2. Any help?

Comment: Not sure of the syntax but you could bind the `TextBox` to the `SelectedValue` of the `ListBox` `<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=StudentsList, Path=SelectedValue.Course}"/>` - though I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would solve this by another way.

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123231/how-to-select-combobox-values-in-selection-changed-event/13125393#13125393)
.

Another way would be that your ViewModel contains a Student-property(e.g. SelectedStudent) which is bind to the SelctedItem of the listView. Then you can handel this by

```
{Binding Path=SelectedStudent.Course}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you bind the listview to a collection of type `SampleData` like below:

**SampleData.cs**

```
public class SampleData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you bind the ListView ItemsSource to a collection. WIt does not matter if you bind ItemsSource property to a property on ViewModel or you bind it in code-behind like the code below.

```
var source = new List<SampleData>();

source.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 1, Text = "AAA" });
source.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 2, Text = "BBB" });
source.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 3, Text = "CCC" });
source.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 4, Text = "DDD" });
source.Add(new SampleData() { Id = 5, Text = "EEE" });
```

You can bind TextBox's Text property to the SelectedItem directly on the View.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListView x:Name="listView1" />

    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listView1, Path=SelectedItem.Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```